# Округление копеек в заказе

Tags: php, битрикс

Написал событие для округление в меньшую сторону суммы заказа. Cобытие действительно отрабатывает убирает у суммы копейки.

Но есть побочный эффект при заказе цену считает два раза(проще говоря купил товаров на 1 руб пишет 2 руб). Вот скрин с заказом для примера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть идеи, но они мне не нравятся. Для начала надо переписывать всю систему. Там не только штучный товар, но и граммы и миллилитры. А это меняет сильно рассчеты.

Там у меня идет деление. Но не учтено что может быть например 0.33. А при делении на него цена увеличивается.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

```
class EventHandlers2
{
    public static function savePropLogs(\Bitrix\Main\Event $event)
    {
        global $USER; // Добавляем глобальную переменную $USER

        // Получаем текущий идентификатор пользователя
        $currentUserId = $USER->GetID();

        // Проверяем, что текущий пользователь - Админ Админ (USER_ID=1)
        if ($currentUserId == 1) {
            $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");
            if ($order->getPaymentSystemId()[0] == 1) {
                $basket = $order->getBasket();
                $basketItems = $basket->getBasketItems();
                $start_price = $basket->getPrice();
                $end_price = floor($basket->getPrice());
                $r = $start_price - $end_price;
                $max_price = 0;
                $max = [
                    'TOTAL_PRICE' => 0,
                    'PRICE' => 0,
                    'ID' => 0,
                ];
                foreach ($basketItems as $item) {
                    if ($max['TOTAL_PRICE'] < $item->getFinalPrice()) {
                        $max['TOTAL_PRICE'] = $item->getFinalPrice();
                        $max['PRICE'] = $item->getFinalPrice() - $r;
                        $max['ID'] = $item->getProductId();
                    }
                }
                foreach ($basketItems as $item) {
                    if ($item->getProductId() == $max['ID']) {
                        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bitrix/php_interface/logs/order1.txt', print_r($max['PRICE'], true));
                        $item->setField('PRICE', $max['PRICE']);
                        $item->setField('CUSTOM_PRICE', 'Y');
                        $item->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
    'sale',
    'OnSaleOrderBeforeSaved',
    ['EventHandlers2', 'savePropLogs']
);
```

Comment: *Вот скрин с заказом для примера* Я вижу дважды посчитанную доставку и полное игнорирование налога.

Comment: Вместо getFinalPrice прописал getPrice. Теперь сумма товаров считается корректно. Но осталась проблема с тем, что доставка считается два раза